# Export from Source Safe

Tags: export, visual-sourcesafe

Is there a way to export files/folders from Source Safe? (i.e. getting rid of all .scc files, just like SVN export)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just do a regular get, then run something like

```
ATTRIB -R *.scc /S
DEL /F /S /Q *.scc
```

The first command removes the read only flag from those files.  The second deletes everything that matches *.scc along the path.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using `DEL /F /S /Q /A SH *.scc` to include hidden and system files as well.

Comment: Beautiful, thanks. I can't wait until the day I never have to see VSS again :). I ran this against all the `*.vspscc` files as well.